# Is java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration thread-safe? What are the alternatives

Tags: java, thread-safety, awt, bufferedimage, swingworker

I'm extending `javax.swing.JComponent` to display a variable number of tiles, which all have the same size.

If a tile needs a new appearance, a `SwingWorker`'s `doInBackground()` renders a new `BufferedImage` for it. In `done()`, the image is stored and `JComponent.repaint()` is called, indicating the updated area and an intended delay. The overridden `JComponent.paintComponent()` will know what to do.

The size of the tiles can be changed via the GUI. Obvioulsy, it could happen that such a request takes place while the the `SwingWorker`'s `StateValue` is `PENDING` or `STARTED`.

I don't see much sense in supporting `cancel()`; it complicates the code and since the actual rendering does not take very long, its effect would be minimal (or even harmful if the worker had to wait longer than it will need to execute). Rather, I would like to add efficiency and have the EDT code not start a new `SwingWorker` if a `PENDING` one exists for the same tile. Then, the `SwingWorker` just needs to fetch the latest settings when `doInBackground()` starts and check whether it should really store its result in `done()`.

So where should the `BufferedImage` used by the `SwingWorker` be cast into existence? These seem to be the options:

- Create it upfront. Drawbacks: The maximum size must be chosen because the specific size is unknown, and since `paintComponent()` may run concurrently, two images of maximum size must be kept for all tiles at all times (think `ViewPort`; a dynamic solution would only require a second image of the actually needed size for visible tiles, temporarily).
- Create it when creating the `SwingWorker`. Drawback: The maximum size must be provided since it's unknown which size is required once `doInBackground()` gets fired.
- Create it in the `SwingWOrker`. Problem: Given that `JComponent.paintComponent()` may have to call `drawImage()` often, it's advisable to use `GraphicsConfiguration.createCompatibleImage()` to create this image. This may break the single-threadedness limitations of AWT.

I would prefer the following, but since `GraphicsConfiguration` belongs to AWT, and the implementation depends on the platform, is this a safe thing to do?

```
  ...
  final GraphicsConfiguration gc = this.getGraphicsConfiguration();
  if ((obj.worker == null) ||
      (obj.worker.getState() != SwingWorker.StateValue.PENDING)) {
    obj.worker = new SwingWorker<BufferedImage, Void>() {
        @Override public BufferedImage doInBackground() {
          ... // acquire size info via synchronised access
          final BufferedImage img = gc.createCompatibleImage(...);
          ...
          return img;
        }
        @Override public void done() {
          if (obj.worker == this) {
            obj.worker = null;       
            try   { obj.image = this.get(); }
            catch (Throwable t) { ... System.exit(1); }
            Outer.this.requestTileRepaint(...);
          }
        }
      };
    obj.worker.execute();
  }
  ...
```

**Clarification**

Looking at the above code, one might argue that there is no real muti-threading issue with this solution, since the `GraphicsConfiguration` object is created on the EDT exclusively for this particular worker. However,

- I was looking at the abstract class implementation and it contains static objects and
- it might be the case that each call to `Component.getGraphicsConfiguration()` returns the same object reference.

I was thinking that the safest approach would be to extract all relevant information from the `GraphicsConfiguration` on the EDT, pass it to the worker, and get a `new BufferedImage()` there with the suitable configuration. But I found some hints on the web that the result may lead to a surprising performance hit for `drawImage()`, suggesting that there might be config aspects which may not be covered explicitly.

Comment: It's been a few years since I did serious Swing development, but I think the `GraphicsConfiguration` will only change when the computer changes screen mode/resolution (either by user preference or another screen/projector is installed), or the window is moved in a multi-monitor setup. You probably need to handle that change in some way. But other than that, how about creating a 1x1 `BufferedImage` up front then creating the full size (off EDT) when you need? Alternatively, cache the `ColorModel` only, and use the `createCompatipleRaster` of that in the `SwingWorker`.

Comment: @haraldK Thank you for these suggestions. How would I create the fully compatible `BufferedImage` with the right size from the 1x1 `BufferedImage`? Via additional `getPropertyNames()` and `getProperty()` calls (as compared to only cacheing the `ColorModel`)? Or via `Image.getScaledInstance()`? Or something else I'm unaware of?

Comment: I was thinking of creating it to call `getType` and use that (if it's not `TYPE_CUSTOM`) to create a new `BufferedImage`. If it's `TYPE_CUSTOM` you would have to fall back to the `ColorModel`.   And: *Don't use `getScaledInstance`!* :-)

Comment: @haraldK I was experimenting along these lines; seems to work rather well. On my system, `OPAQUE` is `RGB` and `TRANSLUCENT` is `ARGB` while `BITMASK` is `CUSTOM`. `BufferedImage`s which are created via the `ColorModel` can be drawn to the `Component`'s `Graphics` object with the same speed as the ones created by `imageType`. I'm still uncertain about the `isRasterPremultiplied` parameter for the `BufferedImage` construction: Should/may/must it be the result of `ColorModel.isAlphaPremultiplied()`?

Comment: Sounds good! Just use the color model then. No need for the 1x1 hack. And, yes, that's what I usually pass. But I think it only matters if the raster actually contains image data. In your case it's all blank.

Comment: @haraldK Have posted some code now. Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Picking up haraldK's ideas, here is a thread-safe solution, which I have tested on a Linux PC with Java SE 1.6.0_26 and a Windows 8.1 notebook with Java SE 1.8.0_40. (Obviously, the code can be improved, buit that's beyond this Q&A.)

On both platforms, performance was comparable adjusted for processor speed, and also on both platforms, `Transparency.BITMASK` was handled via `BufferedImage.TYPE_CUSTOM`, while `Transparency.OPAQUE` and `Transparency.TRANSLUCENT` use specific corresponding `BufferedImage.TYPE_*` values.

Also on both platforms, there was no noticeable performance difference between using any of the two `new BufferedImage()` calls, while `GraphicsConfiguration.createCompatibleImage()` was definitely (30% to 50%) slower.

The whole mechanism is provided by an inner class. The outer class `extend`s `javax.swing.JComponent` so there's no synchronisation at all at that level. However, the `SwingWorker`s are anonymous inner classes and deploy the image creation sync mechanism.

The distinction between the two categories of `BufferedImage.getType()` seems to be unnecessary on the tested platforms, but who knows.

In my case, the innter class also contains other information which the `SwingWorker`s need.

```
private static final class WokerSync
{
  private Object        refImageMutex       = new Object();
  private BufferedImage refImageOpaque      = null;
  private BufferedImage refImageTranspMask  = null;
  private BufferedImage refImageTranslucent = null;

  public void setRefImagesFromEDT(final GraphicsConfiguration grConf) {
    if (grConf != null) {
      synchronized(this.refImageMutex) {
        this.refImageOpaque      = grConf.createCompatibleImage(1, 1, Transparency.OPAQUE);
        this.refImageTranspMask  = grConf.createCompatibleImage(1, 1, Transparency.BITMASK);
        this.refImageTranslucent = grConf.createCompatibleImage(1, 1, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
      }
    }
  }
  private BufferedImage getCompatibleImage(final BufferedImage refImage, final int width, final int height) {
    BufferedImage img = null;
    if (refImage != null) {
      final int grType = refImage.getType();
      if (grType == BufferedImage.TYPE_CUSTOM) {
        final ColorModel               cm = refImage.getColorModel();
        final WritableRaster           wr = cm.createCompatibleWritableRaster(width, height);
        final String[]                 ps = refImage.getPropertyNames();
        final int                      pl = (ps == null) ? 0 : ps.length;
        final Hashtable<String,Object> ph = new Hashtable<String,Object>(pl);
        for (int pi=0; pi<pl; pi++) {
          ph.put(ps[pi], refImage.getProperty(ps[pi]));
        }
        img = new BufferedImage(cm, wr, cm.isAlphaPremultiplied(), ph);
      } else {
        img = new BufferedImage(width, height, grType);
      }
    }
    return img;
  }
  public BufferedImage getCompatibleImageOpaque(final int width, final int height) {
    BufferedImage img = null;
    synchronized(this.refImageMutex) {
      img = this.getCompatibleImage(this.refImageOpaque, width, height);
    }
    return img;
  }
  public BufferedImage getCompatibleImageTranspMask(final int width, final int height) {
    BufferedImage img = null;
    synchronized(this.refImageMutex) {
      img = this.getCompatibleImage(this.refImageTranspMask, width, height);
    }
    return img;
  }
  public BufferedImage getCompatibleImageTranslucent(final int width, final int height) {
    BufferedImage img = null;
    synchronized(this.refImageMutex) {
      img = this.getCompatibleImage(this.refImageTranslucent, width, height);
    }
    return img;
  }
}
```